# next-auth 4 custom base path

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have an app that authenticates against Azure AD using next-auth 4.
It works fine and I can authenticate.

When I try to configure a custom base path `http://localhost:3000/myapp` for the app and call `signIn()` I get a 404 error telling me that `http://localhost:3000/api/auth/error` is not found.

I have configured all the paths like described below.

What confuses me:

- If I use the standard path I notice that [...nextauth.js] gets executed
- If I use a custom path, [...nextauth.js] is not even executed

A similar scenario in next.auth 3 worked just fine.

Comparing to next-auth 3 it looks like next-auth 4 does not honor NEXTAUTH_URL.

What can I do?

.env.local

```
AZURE_CLIENT_ID= ....
AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET=...
AZURE_TENANT_ID=...

JWT_SECRET=...

NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/myapp/api/auth
NEXTAUTH_URL_INTERNAL=http://localhost:3000/mypp/api/auth
NEXT_AUTH_DEBUG=true

APP_BASE_PATH=/myapp
```

next.config.js:

```
const basePath = process.env.APP_BASE_PATH;

module.exports = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  basePath: `${basePath}`,
};
```

[...nextauth.js]`

```
export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      scope: "offline_access User.Read",
      tenantId: process.env.AZURE_TENANT_ID,
    }),
  ],
....
  debug: process.env.NEXT_AUTH_DEBUG,
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you've tried [that solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70717224/how-to-define-a-custom-base-path-when-nextauth-url-doesnt-work/70733866#answer-70733866) ?

Try to edit your _app.tsx and define your base path using the props basePath on your , as in [that example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70717224/how-to-define-a-custom-base-path-when-nextauth-url-doesnt-work/70733866#answer-70733866).