# NEXTAUTH_URL don't work (nextauth redirection to custom path)

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have the following problem, I need to change the custom base path for next auth to work. My application already has an endpoint api/auth for backend server, so I started looking for a solution to this problem.

Following the documentation -
https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#nextauth_url
and opened question -
[How to define a custom base path when NEXTAUTH_URL doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70717224/how-to-define-a-custom-base-path-when-nextauth-url-doesnt-work/70733866?newreg=4fba2d09867343b4a3ea025568656587)

Below is a simple sample code for implementation

```
import type { AuthOptions } from "next-auth";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authConfig: AuthOptions = {
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_ID!,
      clientSecret: process.env.AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET!,
    }),
  ],
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET!,
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
  },
};
```

```
<SessionProvider session={pageProps.session} basePath="/next/api/auth">
```

```
# Auth Providers
AUTH_GOOGLE_ID=
AUTH_GOOGLE_SECRET=

# Auth config
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=
NEXTAUTH_URL="site/next/api/auth"
```

I would appreciate any help and advice to solve this problem.

I changed the value of NEXTAUTH_URL (site/next/api/auth) and basePath in (next/api/auth)

This not work at all in my case and I get errors because next auth can't find anything at this address. What am I doing wrong and how should it work?
GET website/next/api/auth/session 404 (Not Found)
client.js:1 [next-auth][error][CLIENT_FETCH_ERROR]

Tried to solve this problem in app and pages routing and got the same result. The problem seems to have gone away in the latest beta version (5.0.0-beta.4), but I would like to use a more stable version if possible, since without proper documentation it is hard to migrate all my methods from [...nextauth].ts of the previous current version.

Comment: Have you found a solution? Can you put it here? I have the same issue.